# Precision loss when passing arguments using va_list and printf

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions

I have a logging function which works like this:

```
// public function:
void ConsoleUI::log(const std::string& format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    log(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// overloaded private function:
void ConsoleUI::log(const std::string& format, va_list args) {
    //wprintw( outWin, format.c_str(), args);
    //wprintw( outWin, "\n");
    printf( format.c_str(), args);
    printf( "\n");
}
```

(Side note: This should do the exact same thing as just a normal printf, so it's pretty useless in this state. That's because this is a minumal working example. In the end, this should work with ncurses - see commented section.)

I then create an instance of the ConsoleUI class, called ui:

```
ConsoleUI ui;
```

And later I use it to log stuff, more precisely, a time_duration in microseconds:

```
now = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
boost::posix_time::time_duration delta = now - lastTime;
double dt = 1e-6*(double)delta.total_microseconds();
lastTime = now;

ui.log( "logged dt: %f", dt );
ui.log( "logged dt 2: %lu", delta.total_microseconds());
printf( "dt: %f\n", dt);
printf( "dt 2: %lu\n", delta.total_microseconds());
```

The output I get:

```
logged dt: 0.000000
logged dt 2: 140736013247624
dt: 0.018739
dt 2: 18739
```

What I expected:

```
logged dt: 0.018739
logged dt 2: 18739
dt: 0.018739
dt 2: 18739
```

Note that over multiple calls of this, the values in the last two lines change slightly (as is to be expected of a delta time) and the first two values don't change - which looks like there's something wrong with the format.

So, bottom line: Calling printf directly works, but passing it down the logger and then calling printf doesn't work...

Comment: With a `va_list`, you should call `vprintf`, not `printf`.

Comment: Duh. Thanks. That was it. Thanks for the fast reply!

If you want to change your comment to an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to have a reference as the last argument before `...` . Change the format to `char const *` (unless your compiler supports the reference as an extension)

Comment: Seeing as though you're using c++, can I recommend not using va_list's at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't actually pass your arguments from `log` to `printf`, you are passing a `va_list` - this is the right solution, but you can't pass a `va_list` to printf.

This line:

```
    printf( format.c_str(), args);
```

prints `args` with the format in `format`. Given that `args` is of the type `va_list` (typically implemented in the comiler ABI as a void pointer) it will not represent the data that you expect in the format string. If you use

```
   vprintf( format.c_str(), args);
```

it should work just fine, that's what `vprintf` is for.

(Note that it's nothing to do with "loss of precision" - it's passing incorrect type of argument to printf - and since it's a programmaticly formulated string, even enabling warnings is not going to work).